# Search bar should ignore “-”, Caps and spaces (132D123 and 132 d 123 should return true) ? php

Tags: php

Currently when i search the registration number 131-D-12345 I have to type the hyphens to get the results, but I wish to ignore  “-”, caps and spaces (so for instance "132D123" and "132 d 123" should return true).

How can I do that in PHP?

```
<?php
        require('/home/s3022041/sqlC/dbConnect.php');
        if(isset($_POST['searchById']))
        {
            $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['get_id']);
        $id = $_POST['get_id'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE Registration_Number = '$id' ";
     $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    ?>
```

Comment: Store the data in a normalized form. Then everytime you search normalize the input. Problem solved

Comment: Is the format of the registration numbers always [number][ 1 alphabet ][number]?

Comment: Please share more details. Why not remove such data from the database? Also, be warned that the given SQL query is open for SQL injection

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly
Your database looks something like this example

```
  1 | 987-D-987
  2 | 654-E-456
  3 | 789-D-123
  4 | 678-Z-123
```

And for example,if you search for 654 e 456 you are expecting to get entry 2.

Well you could use good old string functions...

```
<?php
 
$id = $_POST['get_id'];

$stp1 = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $id); //grab only the alphanumerics
   $stp2 = strtoupper($stp1); //Make all alphabets uppercase
     $stp3 = preg_replace('/\d+/', '',$stp2); //extract the alphabets part
       $newsearchid = str_replace($stp3,"-".$stp3."-",$stp2); //put hyphens before and after the alphabet part

        echo "spaces or lower case .i will return this".$newsearchid; //now the search string looks like one in the database

        require('/home/s3022041/sqlC/dbConnect.php');
        if(isset($_POST['searchById']))
        {
            $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $newsearchid);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE Registration_Number = '$newsearchid' ";
     $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

?>
```

if you search for 
`"987 d 987" or "987     d987" or "987d987" or "987D987" or "987-d-987" or "987,d@987"`
 you will still get entry 1 from db.
Basically any search in the format **[number][alphabet][number]** will always return true

Answer (score -1):

Do I understand correctly that the registration numbers in the database dò contain the hyphens ?

In that case, you should modify your query to hold wildcards (e.g. https://www.guru99.com/wildcards.html)

As for the case, either convert the case of the PHP variable before entering it in the query ( strtoupper(), strtolower() ), or try to solve your case in your table definition.

If the database entries do not hold the hyphens, you can filter them out the variable using a replace or preg_replace() to remove them.

*Edit*

if I assume your database holds very uniform inputs, like this :

```
     ID | registration
    ----+---------------
      1 | 132D123
      2 | 234D324
      3 | 456D546
      4 | 678D123
```

then you can prepare your search term as follows :

```
$searchReg = $_POST['get_id'] ;  // take your unmodified POST-ed registration
$searchReg = strtoupper($searchReg) ;   // make all characters upper-case, as DB entries are all uppercase
$searchReg = preg_replace("/[\s-]?/", "", $searchReg) ; // replace all whitespaces and hyphens by an empty string - i.e. remove them

if(isset($_POST['searchById']))
        {
            $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $searchReg);
        $id = $searchReg;
...
```

If however, your database is not formatted very strictly, like :

```
     ID | registration
    ----+---------------
      1 | 132D123
      2 | 234d324
      3 | 456-D-546
      4 | 678-d-123
```

Then you need to make your SQL query cover the searchterm using wildcards :

```
$searchReg = $_POST['get_id'] ;  // take your unmodified POST-ed registration
$searchReg = preg_replace( "/[\s-]?/", "%", $searchReg) ; // replace all whitespaces and hyphens by a SQL wildcard

if(isset($_POST['searchById']))
        {
            $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $searchReg);
            $id = $searchReg;
            $query = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE Registration_Number LIKE '" . strtoupper($id) ."' OR Registration_Number LIKE '" . strtolower($id) . "'" ;
...
```

Comment: So my system works as follows: its using the crud options, so the users adds their car registration system by filling out a form and in that form they are required to use hyphens while entering the registration number, then the information is saved in a table and then I search their details by searching their registration number. So while I'm searching the registration number I am required to ignore “-”, caps and spaces (so for instance "132D123" and "132 d 123" should return true). So how would I do that?

Comment: any idea regarding this ?

Comment: The given SQL query is widely open for SQL injection and should never be used like that.

Comment: @NicoHaase yes - except I'm trying to explain something without cluttering the original question - same reason why I'm working with intermediate values and step-wise operations, and not strtoupper(preg_replace(...)).
But feel free to leave the OP hints or pointers to best practice examples